# How to check if two adjacent characters are duplicated?

Tags: python

This is the exercise I was asked to do:

> A DNA sequence is made up of a combination of codons, which are any 3
> different letters belonging to the symbol set {A,C,G,T}, for example
> ACT, ACG, TCG... A gene segment is a set of genes. combination of at
> least 3 codons starting with ATG and ending with TAA, TAG or TGA.
> Write a program to check if a gene segment is valid or not ?Here is my
> work

Here is my work

```py
sequence = input().upper()
valid_dna = "ACGT"
sequence = sequence.replace(" ", "")
for i in sequence:
    if i in valid_dna:  
        count = 1
    else:
        count=0
    if count==1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

It returns "YES" for all input as "A,C,G,T", but it can't return "NO" when consecutive characters are duplicate. How to fix it?

Comment: the rules don't say that two consecutive repeated letters are invalid, in fact the rules state that TAA is a valid end codon

Comment: "How to fix" - what is there to fix? You haven't even implemented the logic required for your desired result. Stack Overflow is not the place to have homework done for you.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to share the actual requirements for what is considered a valid or invalid segment. Even if you had the requirements listed, we still have nothing to "fix" in your code, since you haven't implemented anything besides the basic boilerplate code that I can see. It's not self-explanatory what you're checking for, or what your requirements are. If it's literally just checking that all the characters are within the valid set, then use python `set`s to do the comparison.

Comment: You can do the entire thing by matching the sequence against a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the title of the question then...

To find out if a sequence of characters contains adjacent duplicated characters:

```
def adjacent(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal No. It is correct as written. If it was as you suggest then the string, for example, 'ACC' would return False

Comment: Whoops, range goes up to the range value, ofcourse.